# Using the Amazon AWS sdk - You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run a query to check all of my Amazon EC2 instances.

I used the demo app template, and it runs fine with my credentials, but I don't quite understand how it uses the aws key and secret key.

In my app.config (console demo app):

```
<!-- Amazon AWS API keys. -->
<add key="AWSAccessKey" value="ASDASDASDASD"/>
<add key="AWSSecretKey" value="asdasdf/qwerqwerqwerqwerqwer"/>
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1" />
```

**It runs fine and lists my instances:**

```
// Print the number of Amazon EC2 instances.
IAmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client();
DescribeInstancesRequest ec2Request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
DescribeInstancesResponse ec2Response = ec2.DescribeInstances(ec2Request);

var numInstances = ec2Response.Reservations.Count;
```

Notice how it's not really accessing the App.config values, that's the root of my confusion.

---

Now in the real deal app, my MVC3 application. I'm trying the exact same thing, but I'm getting this error:

```
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

And in my `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- Amazon AWS API keys. -->
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="asdfasdfasdfasdf"/>
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="adsfasdfadf/asdfasdfasdfasdf"/>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1" />
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you create an AWS client without explicitly supplying credentials (i.e.,  using a no-argument constructor), the SDK will look in various  places for credentials, including the appSettings section of your App.config or Web.config. It isn't clear why they're not getting picked up from your Web.config in this case though. What you've provided seems correct.

Comment: I'm such a git - I don't know how/why, but the actual string value being called by `ConfigurationManager` was incorrect. And it took me 3 hours to actually notice using the debugger. Time for some mocca!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your issue is, but is there any chance you are running the working code on an EC2 instance, and the non-working code you are running locally?

If your EC2 instance was setup with an IAM role, and that IAM role has permissions that it needs, you don't need to provide the credentials at all - they are 'inherited' from the instance *(btw: this is also the recommended way of supplying the credentials to the sdk so they are not floating around in a config file).*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-roles.html72

If thats not what is going on, perhaps you could be a bit clearer - how do you know in your first example that its not accessing your credentials?

Comment: I'm using the New Project templates, and a windows pops up asking me for my aws key and secret key. How can I determine if I'm `running the working code on an EC2 instance`; note that I'm running the demo project locally on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: So I guess the question is, when generating the demo app using the New Project template, what does it do that's so special? Wouldn't adding the keys to the web.config  in my MVC3 project be enough?

Comment: My bad. Url not loading.